# how do I filter search results according to node criteria - drupal?

Tags: search, drupal

I am needing to filter search results according to a specific node type, but prioritize the results.

First listed must be the results that have image/images attached to the node. Then the nodes with no image.

Hopefully this will clarify. My site has business listings. Some are paid clients (have images in listing), others are non paid (no images, just listing). I need the have the paid clients listing displaying before non paid clients in search results.

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a view, with respective filters and add sorting criteria with image fields!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. How do I go about having search results displayed using that view?

Comment: There are two ways, either you create a custom module and using hook_search, modify the default search feature. Or create a view with page display, having a URL. Add the fields you want to display in search result and add exposed/default filters to refine the search. You can learn more about creating veiws on views project page.